# Handling servlets exceptions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, exception, glassfish

I am getting troubles with handling exceptions in web servlet app.
I've created ErrorHandler servlet, which handles all incoming exceptions and added entry in web.xml file :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ServletPackage.ErrorHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ErrorHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

The problem is the server does not invoke ErrorHandler servlet at all. 
Glassfish just throws Exception in the console and web browser refreshes the servlet which thrown exception (with no data due to unhandled exception).

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[SessionChecker]: Servlet.service() for servlet SessionChecker threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Forced exception thrown
    at ServletPackage.SessionChecker.processRequest(SessionChecker.java:158)
    at ServletPackage.SessionChecker.doPost(SessionChecker.java:174)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
   .
   .
   .
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any advices? I really need to make it work as it should and no bloody idea why ErrorHandler is not able to handle any exception. Maybe something is wrong with my train of thought and It not going to work at all in this way?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.  All over the web are examples as you've shown and when I tried it it seemed that my handler servlet was just being ignored completely.

What worked for me to make sure that my error handling servlet implemented both doGet and doPost:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    processError(request, response);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    processError(request, response);
}

private void processError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
    ...
}
```

The examples that I had based my servlet on had only implemented doGet.  So while my servlet was being loaded and called on errors, nothing was happening with those errors.  Implementing doPost to handle the errors the same way solved this for me.

Comment: This is a very useful answer!

Answer (score -1):

If the exception is being thrown from your web server the exception handler you have declared in the web.xml is not ever going to deal with it.

The exception handler in the web.xml is to handle request coming into the web server.

Comment: Is there any way to check out my ErrorHandler then? I suppose that it's impossible to throw an exception in HTTP request coming from website, and if it's not possible to throw it from other servlet as You said, I don't really understand the purpose and goal of doing that. On turtorialspoint.com I read "When a servlet throws an exception, the web container searches the configurations in web.xml that use the exception-type element for a match with the thrown exception type.". That's exactly what I try to do, throwing exception from the servlet code.

Comment: I haven't used this mechanism before. But is it possible that the exception type needs to be an exact match, i.e. match on a fully qualified classname, not matching on any classnmae in the hierarchy of the type.

Comment: Does not matter, I tried with ServletException or IOException and result is the same. However I wonder if the problem could be caused by filter class that affects all servlets in my project.

Comment: "it possible that the exception type needs to be an exact match" - not really. The `java.lang.Exception` should suffice (`Throwable`) is preferable. But this is some kind of chicken-egg scenario: OP has defined an error handler, but the error handler itself is not working. What would you expect the container to do in that instance?

Comment: @ baka1408, Are there any error in the logs after Tomcat has started?

Comment: Of course it is handling your exceptions. Otherwise the whole exception handling would be useless. Therefore -1